# jupyter notebook installation issue using pip

Tags: python, path, jupyter-notebook

I had a problem with jupyter notebook. Every time I started a notebook, kernel died.

So, I decided to uninstall jupyter notebook using pip:

```
pip uninstall jupyter notebook
```

After successful uninstallation, I installed again, using same pip:

```
pip install jupyter notebook
```

Then, as usually, I typed in cmd:

```
jupyter notebook
```

But got this error:

**'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

So I checked the location of IPython, and found out that now the right file, which I want to call is **jupyter-notebook**, which different from **jupyter notebook** by dash sign. If I run **jupyter-notebook** from cmd everything works.

Can anyone explain, what happened and why the file now called jupyter-notebook?

Thank You

Comment: @SuatAtanPhD same result. I am just curious of why the syntax changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because pip uses the legacy Python 2.
Use pip3 to install:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook  #to start jupyter notebook
```

I highly recommend installing Anaconda.
Download Anaconda [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#linux).

Then use :

```
bash
```

to install it.

Good Luck.

Comment: just an addition, if you are trying to re-install jupyter notebook, please make sure to uninstall it first  ```pip3 uninstall jupyter notebook```. Then ```pip3 install jupyter notebook```. This worked for me for the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without installing Anaconda, or conda:

```
sudo easy_install pip==20.3.4
pip2 install virtualenv
virtualenv jupyter
source jupyter/bin/activate
pip2 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

This solution was tested on:
**Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS

Release:    16.04

Codename:   xenial**
It was run on 32bit Chromenotebook, with Firefox vs NetSurf installed on xenial

Jupyter notebook will be open automatically. However, everytime loging in on Jupiter again, at first source needs to be activated:

```
source jupyter/bin/activate
```

and then:

```
jupyter notebook
```

to start

[image: terminal and Firefox screens on xenial]

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you always use conda instead of pip to install the Jupyter Notebook.
In your case, for example, I will recommend:

```
conda install jupyter notebook
```

and not  `pip install jupyter notebook` I can see that most of the problems that you described there are environment related and hence you can often run into environment issues while using pip to install jupyter